# Model positioning during multiple close combats after removing models

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

Here is the scenario.

A multiple close combat scenario. 3 units are attacking one of my units. One is attacking the front. 1 on my left flank. 1 on my right flank. I have 15 models in the unit.

3 models are killed from the frontal attack. I remove 3 units from the rear of my unit. Now 2 models are in the rear of my unit. Who can those 2 models attack? Do they slide over to the right flank or the left? Or does the controller of the unit get to decide where they slide to? I read a rule that said they are assumed to slide over to engage in combat, but which side? Do they slide from side to side during one phase of combat?

If they are on the right flank, can the enemy at the left flank claim an extra model is in base contact with the last row even though they are not touching the actual model that is there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact situation is covered under Incomplete Ranks in the Close Combat section of the rules (pg 49.)

> If the unit is fighting to its rear (**or fighting to both flanks**) some
>   enemy models might not end up in base contact because of the models in
>   the incomplete rear rank. In this specific situation, **the models can
>   fight across the gap, even if not physically in base-to-base contact**.
>   In reality, the chargers would not have stopped one step away from the
>   enemy and would have moved in to continue the fight — treat these
>   models as being in base contact with the enemy.

They count as being in base contact even though there is a gap.

Comment: I read that rule. I did not read it correctly. I thought it was only referring to 1 flank being fought, not two. Thanks